# Sanity Studio CMS on initialise script (upstart)

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, sanity

Is there a way to hook into the Sanity Studio initialise step? Or perhaps start the Studio from a js module so I can wrap it in some logic?

My motive is, in development it can be confusing which Project Instance, Dataset or Project name I'm on. When running `npm start` I get the following output

```
⠹ Compiling...webpack built d689d86d2ed85bc7df76 in 3970ms
✔ Compiling...
Content Studio successfully compiled! Go to http://localhost:3333
```

But I'd like to add an additional line to this to dump

```
ProjectName: $Name ProjectId: $ID Dataset: $Dataset
```

There is a `.env` file but these values can also be overridden by config in `sanity.json`.

Logging these values for a ***sanity*** check would be very handy in dev.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a command on the cli to execute a script with the Sanity context. `sanity exec` the page [here](https://www.sanity.io/docs/exec) mentions it but doesn't mention how to consume it in a script.

Making this `info.ts` file

```js
import client from 'part:@sanity/base/client'

console.log(client.config())
```

Which imports the sanity part `client`. And from here we can dump the config to console.

Adding this to the package config enables `npm run info`

```json
"info": "sanity exec info.ts"
```

As it's initialising Sanity it's a little slow to include in a start command `npm run info && npm run start` because this initialises Sanity twice. But handy to run once off to check, including this in the cli would be better.